# How to get my value to return it in the description of discord webhook

Tags: javascript, twitter, discord.js, streaming

I'm completely stuck with getting one of my variable.
First i'm streaming twitter status then i want to send the content into a discord channel.
But like i said i don't know how to get through. Here's my code:

```
const Twit = require('twit')
const notifier = require('node-notifier');
const open = require('open');
const franc = require('franc')
const fetch = require('fetch')
const Discord = require('discord.js')

const apikey = '....'
const apiSecretKey = '....'
const accessToken = '....'
const accessTokenSecret = '....'

var T = new Twit({
    consumer_key: apikey,
    consumer_secret: apiSecretKey,
    access_token: accessToken,
    access_token_secret: accessTokenSecret,
});

(async () => {

    

    // 3. REAL TIME MONITORING USING STREAM (LOCATION)   
    var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { follow: 'ID TWITTER' })
    return stream

    //SHOW NOTIFICATION FOR EACH RECEIVED TWEET
    stream.on('tweet', function (tweet) {
        console.log(tweet.text);
        let url = `https://twitter.com/${tweet.user.screen_name}/status/${tweet.id_str}`

        notifier.notify({
            title: tweet.user.name,
            message: tweet.text
           
        });

        notifier.on('click', async function (notifierObject, options, event) {
            console.log('clicked');
            await open(url);
        });
    })    
})();


fetch(
    'https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/796157635761143809/bQ6XEolKYL0sk4DKJgJh-dF-Qg5lAvj7pzFNARx_L4I1-I0lnxZehppLIHgY06JToxie',
    {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            // the username to be displayed
            username: 'webhook',
            // contents of the message to be sent
            content:
                'user mention: <@279098137484722176>, role mention: <@&496160161459863552>, channel mention: <#508500699458306049>',
            // enable mentioning of individual users or roles, but not @everyone/@here
            allowed_mentions: {
                parse: ['users', 'roles'],
            },
            // embeds to be sent
            embeds: [
                {
                    // decimal number colour of the side of the embed
                    color: 11730954,
                    // author
                    // - icon next to text at top (text is a link)
                    author: {
                        name: 'dragonwocky',
                        url: 'https://dragonwocky.me/',
                        icon_url: 'https://dragonwocky.me/assets/avatar.jpg',
                    },
                    // embed title
                    // - link on 2nd row
                    title: 'title',
                    url:
                        'https://gist.github.com/dragonwocky/ea61c8d21db17913a43da92efe0de634',
                    // thumbnail
                    // - small image in top right corner.
                    thumbnail: {
                        url:
                            'https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/411256446638882837/9a12fc7810795ded801fdb0401db0be6.png',
                    },
                    // embed description
                    // - text on 3rd row
                    description: stream,
                    // custom embed fields: bold title/name, normal content/value below title
                    // - located below description, above image.
                    fields: [
                        {
                            name: 'field 1',
                            value: 'value',
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'field 2',
                            value: 'other value',
                        },
                    ],
                    // image
                    // - picture below description(and fields)
                    image: {
                        url:
                            'http://tolkiengateway.net/w/images/thumb/7/75/J.R.R._Tolkien_-_Ring_verse.jpg/300px-J.R.R._Tolkien_-_Ring_verse.jpg',
                    },
                    // footer
                    // - icon next to text at bottom
                    footer: {
                        text: 'footer',
                        icon_url:
                            'https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/411256446638882837/9a12fc7810795ded801fdb0401db0be6.png',
                    },
                },
            ],
        }),
    }
);
```

If someone can help me by giving a clue or something i'll be grateful !

Ps: i'm new in JS but before posting that i did my own research without success :/

Thanks all !

Comment: So you want to post a message on Discord when a new tweet is published?

Comment: yes i want to sent it to a discord channel. So the First step is to get the variable where the tweet is then sent it with the webhook